# Trouble with imlib2 while installing Tint2

Tags: installation, linux-mint, dependencies, cmake

I'm trying to install Tint2 dock through its git repository on, Linux Mint. Following the instructions, i got to the `cmake ..` part, ran it, and received this output after a while:

```
-- Checking for module 'imlib2>=1.4.2'
--   No package 'imlib2' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:463 (message):
  A required package was not found
```

I tried finding `imlib2` but couldn't find many relevant pages that mention it, and none actually offered a working package. Can't seem to install any working version of it, and it's apparently needed. What options do I have, and why do I encounter this problem?
I'm running Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa on a 64-bit i5 processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `imlib2` library and development files can be installed through:

```
sudo apt install libimlib2 libimlib2-dev
```